# Convert List of names to Dictionary, where each entry corresponds to names that begin with a certain letter

Tags: c#, list, dictionary

I created some method that returns a `Dictionary<string, List<Employee>>` in this method i loop through a `List<Employee>` and look for the firstname and add this alphabetical to my Dictionary

Look at the following example:

- Employees

  - Eijk, Jordy
  - Doe, John
  - Doe, Jane
  - etc.

where the first part is the Lastname and the second part is the Firstname

My method creates a Dictionary like this

- "D", List ({Doe, John}, {Doe, Jane})
- "E", List ({Eijk, Jordy})

The method:

```
public async Task<Dictionary<string, List<Employee>>> GetAllOrderdedByNameAsync()
    {
        var dbList = await _employeeRepository.ListAsync();
        var employees = dbList.Select(FromDb).ToList();
        var empDict = new Dictionary<string, List<Employee>>();
        for (char c = 'A'; c <= 'Z'; c++)
        {
            var list = employees.Where(employee => employee.LastName.StartsWith(c.ToString(), StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)).ToList();
            if (list.Count > 0)
            {
                empDict.Add(c.ToString(), list);
            }
        }
        return empDict;
    }
```

Now my question... Is there a better way to do this? I will keep the `List<Employee>` as input and need the `Dictionary<string,List<Employee>>` as output, so please don't say i need to return something else.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It sounds like you really want an `ILookup<string, Employee>` which is precisely a dictionary where each key maps to potentially multiple values. Yes, you *can* create a `Dictionary<string, List<Employee>>` but I would *strongly* advise you not to. You say you "need" the `Dictionary<string,List<Employee>>` - why?

The lookup code would be:

```
var lookup = list.ToLookup(x => x.Substring(x.LastName(0, 1)),
                           StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);
```

To get a dictionary, if you *really* have a good reason, you can use:

```
var dictionary = list.GroupBy(x => x.Substring(x.LastName(0, 1)))
                     .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.ToList(), 
                                   StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);
```

... but as I say, I would *strongly* recommend using a type which already represents exactly what you're looking for, in a more concise fashion. (It also has the nice feature of allowing you to look up by any key, and just returning an empty sequence if there are no entries.)

You might also want to consider using `char` as your key instead of `string`, given that you're only dealing with a single character - and also consider what you want to happen to last names such as "de Havilland" or ones beginning with an accented character. (In other words, you may want to perform some normalization.)

Comment: wow, you type so fast, is there an advantage to using `Substring` over `First` on `LastName` (that is the only difference in my answer to yours)

Comment: @sa_ddam213: Well `First` will return a `char` rather than `string`.... you might as well use `[0]` at that point.

Comment: ahh, never mind, `char` vs `string` would be the answer I guess :)

Comment: Hi Jon, Thanks for this answer. But there is one problem. I realy need to have a list of Employees. I'm using it for a GridView (StoreApp) in combination with a grouped CollectionViewSource

Comment: @Jordy: If you need a list, why did you ask for a dictionary? If you need a list per entry, you can always call ToList on each item from a lookup  when you need it.

Comment: @JonSkeet No it is different. The Source of my CollectionViewSource is the dictionary. Bacause i don't wont to create a class with 2 properties that i will be filling.

Comment: @JordyvanEijk: Okay, I'm now confused about what an extra class has to do with anything... but so long as you're happy with the result, that's fine. (I would still tend to favour a lookup here, but...)

Comment: @JonSkeet but the lookup will return just a char or string as the key and a single employee that meets this key. So if i have 20 employees inside my list the Lookup will return 20 results and i need to group the employees with the same first letter of Lastname

Comment: @JordyvanEijk: No, it won't. Did you read the documentation for `ILookup`? Each entry in a lookup is a single key and *multiple* values. It basically *is* a `Dictionary<TKey, List<TValue>>` but in a slightly different form.

Comment: @JonSkeet If i hovered over it yesterday i saw that it was an ILookup<string, Employee>. I will try it again and see what it will give me.

Comment: @JordyvanEijk: That's just the type arguments - you need to look at how they're *used* within the API.

Answer (score 0):

I'm so so sorry for not believing in you ;)

It indeed works like it supposed to do. After looking up [ILookup on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534291(v=vs.100).aspx) it was still a bit unclear of how it is working. But i managed to implement it.

Here is some sample code for everyone who want to know how i did it.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleSandbox
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var vm = new ViewModel();

        var lookupEmployees = vm.GetAllOrderedByName();

        foreach (var group in lookupEmployees)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(group.Key);
            foreach (var employee in group)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\t"+employee);
            }
        }
        Console.Read();
    }
}

public class ViewModel
{
    public ViewModel()
    {
        //Fill Employees
        Employees = new List<Employee>
        {
            new Employee{ FirstName = "Jordy", LastName = "Eijk van"},
            new Employee{ FirstName = "Jon", LastName = "Skeet"},
            new Employee{ FirstName = "John", LastName = "Doe"},
            new Employee{ FirstName = "Jane", LastName = "Doe"},
            new Employee{ FirstName = "Jack", LastName = "Ripper the"}
        };
    }

    public List<Employee> Employees { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Get the Employees by name
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public ILookup<string, Employee> GetAllOrderedByName()
    {
        return Employees
            .OrderBy(e=>e.LastName)
            .ThenBy(e=>e.FirstName)
            .ToLookup(e => e.LastName.Substring(0, 1), StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);
    }
}

public class Employee
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("{0} {1}", LastName, FirstName);
    }
}
}
```

Its a simple Console application